# Delete duplicate records from a table

Tags: sql, oracle

I selected few records from the database using the following query

```
    SELECT distinct po.linetot, TOT.TOTQTY, TOT.TOTamount, po.buy_qty_due, DUPS.* FROM 
          (
          select WOC.ver_type,WOC.WO_NO, WOC.COST, WOC.QTY, WOC.REQUISITION_NO, WOC.REQUISITION_LINE_NO, WOC.REQUISITION_RELEASE_NO, WOC.RELEASE_NO, WOC.VER_NO, WOC.VER_DATE, 
          WOC.INVOICE_ID, WOC.PURCHASE_ORDER_NO , WOC.PURCHASE_LINE_NO, WOC.PURCHASE_RELEASE_NO , COUNT(WOC.VER_NO) 
          from work_order_coding_tab WOC
          where WOC.ver_type='I'
          group by WOC.ver_type, WOC.WO_NO, woc.cost, WOC.QTY, WOC.REQUISITION_NO, WOC.REQUISITION_LINE_NO, WOC.REQUISITION_RELEASE_NO, WOC.RELEASE_NO, WOC.VER_NO, WOC.VER_DATE,
          WOC.INVOICE_ID, WOC.PURCHASE_ORDER_NO, WOC.PURCHASE_LINE_NO, WOC.PURCHASE_RELEASE_NO
          having  count(WOC.ver_no)>1
          ) DUPS
    LEFT JOIN     
          (
          select WOC.ver_type,WOC.WO_NO, WOC.QTY, WOC.amount, SUM (WOC.QTY) AS TOTQTY , SUM (WOC.amount) AS TOTamount, WOC.REQUISITION_NO, WOC.REQUISITION_LINE_NO, WOC.REQUISITION_RELEASE_NO, WOC.RELEASE_NO, WOC.VER_NO, WOC.VER_DATE, 
          WOC.INVOICE_ID, WOC.PURCHASE_ORDER_NO , WOC.PURCHASE_LINE_NO, WOC.PURCHASE_RELEASE_NO  
          from work_order_coding_tab WOC
          where WOC.ver_type='I'
          group by WOC.ver_type, WOC.WO_NO, woc.amount, WOC.QTY, WOC.REQUISITION_NO, WOC.REQUISITION_LINE_NO, WOC.REQUISITION_RELEASE_NO, WOC.RELEASE_NO, WOC.VER_NO, WOC.VER_DATE,
          WOC.INVOICE_ID, WOC.PURCHASE_ORDER_NO , WOC.PURCHASE_LINE_NO, WOC.PURCHASE_RELEASE_NO
          ) TOT
      ON TOT.VER_NO=DUPS.VER_NO and tot.purchase_order_no=dups.purchase_order_no and tot.purchase_line_no=dups.purchase_line_no and tot.purchase_release_no=dups.purchase_release_no

    LEFT JOIN 
          (
          select POL.order_no, POL.line_no, POL.release_no, POL.buy_qty_due, POL.buy_unit_price , POL.buy_qty_due * POL.buy_unit_price as linetot, POL.ORIGINAL_QTY from purchase_Order_line_tab  POL
          )PO
      on PO.order_no=dups.PURCHASE_ORDER_NO and PO.line_no=dups.PURCHASE_LINE_NO and po.release_no=dups.PURCHASE_RELEASE_NO


    where po.linetot<> tot.totamount
    order by dups.wo_no, dups.PURCHASE_ORDER_NO, dups.PURCHASE_LINE_NO, dups.PURCHASE_RELEASE_NO
```

What I need to do is deleting the duplicate records from the 'work_order_coding_tab'.

But I have no idea on how to delete duplicates from the table.

The keys of 'work_order_coding_tab' are WO_NO and ROW no. Does anyone have any idea on how I can do this

P.S I tried to consider one of the answers given and wrote the following query for the first two left joins

```
    SELECT * from WORK_ORDER_CODING_TAB WOC1
      where 
      woc1.row_no <
      ANY (
        select
        woc.row_no
                    FROM 
                    WORK_ORDER_CODING_TAB woc
          where 
            WOC.ver_type=WOC1.ver_type AND 
            WOC.WO_NO=WOC1.WO_NO AND 
            woc.cost=WOC1.cost AND
            WOC.QTY=WOC1.QTY AND 
            WOC.REQUISITION_NO=WOC1.REQUISITION_NO AND 
            WOC.REQUISITION_LINE_NO=WOC1.REQUISITION_LINE_NO AND 
            WOC.REQUISITION_RELEASE_NO=WOC1.REQUISITION_RELEASE_NO AND 
            WOC.RELEASE_NO=WOC1.RELEASE_NO AND 
            WOC.VER_NO=WOC1.VER_NO AND 
            WOC.VER_DATE=WOC1.VER_DATE AND
            WOC.INVOICE_ID=WOC1.INVOICE_ID AND 
            WOC.PURCHASE_ORDER_NO=WOC1.PURCHASE_ORDER_NO AND 
            WOC.PURCHASE_LINE_NO=WOC1.PURCHASE_LINE_NO AND 
            WOC.PURCHASE_RELEASE_NO=WOC1.PURCHASE_RELEASE_NO and 
            WOC.ver_type='I' and
            WOC.VER_NO=WOC1.VER_NO 

      )
```

But it doesn't give me the same results, as the first query

Comment: `delete from tbl where id in (....show distinct items ID with duplicates )`

Comment: @Hinu, by row no did you mean rownum?. I am asking this because i am not able to see row no column in your query.

Comment: Hi.. its ROW_NO. yes we cannot consider ROW_NO because, if it is considered, I'm unable to get duplicates from the query since wo_no and row_No are primary keys. That is why row_no has been not considered

Comment: What do your `select` queries have to do with deleting? All we need is the structure of the table you want to dedupe and some sample data. When two rows have the same WO_NO and ROW_NO, which one do you want to delete?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in your comment i have used wn_no as the key to delete the records. I am using row_number analytical function to delete the records.

The below query helps you select the duplicate records and then you have can figure out which rows from WORK_ORDER_CODING_TAB  to delete based on wn_no.

**Code:**

```
select * from(
select taba.*,row_number() over(partition by WO_NO order by null) from (
SELECT distinct po.linetot, TOT.TOTQTY, TOT.TOTamount, po.buy_qty_due, DUPS.* FROM 
          (
          select WOC.ver_type,WOC.WO_NO, WOC.COST, WOC.QTY, WOC.REQUISITION_NO, WOC.REQUISITION_LINE_NO, WOC.REQUISITION_RELEASE_NO, WOC.RELEASE_NO, WOC.VER_NO, WOC.VER_DATE, 
          WOC.INVOICE_ID, WOC.PURCHASE_ORDER_NO , WOC.PURCHASE_LINE_NO, WOC.PURCHASE_RELEASE_NO , COUNT(WOC.VER_NO) 
          from work_order_coding_tab WOC
          where WOC.ver_type='I'
          group by WOC.ver_type, WOC.WO_NO, woc.cost, WOC.QTY, WOC.REQUISITION_NO, WOC.REQUISITION_LINE_NO, WOC.REQUISITION_RELEASE_NO, WOC.RELEASE_NO, WOC.VER_NO, WOC.VER_DATE,
          WOC.INVOICE_ID, WOC.PURCHASE_ORDER_NO, WOC.PURCHASE_LINE_NO, WOC.PURCHASE_RELEASE_NO
          having  count(WOC.ver_no)>1
          ) DUPS
    LEFT JOIN     
          (
          select WOC.ver_type,WOC.WO_NO, WOC.QTY, WOC.amount, SUM (WOC.QTY) AS TOTQTY , SUM (WOC.amount) AS TOTamount, WOC.REQUISITION_NO, WOC.REQUISITION_LINE_NO, WOC.REQUISITION_RELEASE_NO, WOC.RELEASE_NO, WOC.VER_NO, WOC.VER_DATE, 
          WOC.INVOICE_ID, WOC.PURCHASE_ORDER_NO , WOC.PURCHASE_LINE_NO, WOC.PURCHASE_RELEASE_NO  
          from work_order_coding_tab WOC
          where WOC.ver_type='I'
          group by WOC.ver_type, WOC.WO_NO, woc.amount, WOC.QTY, WOC.REQUISITION_NO, WOC.REQUISITION_LINE_NO, WOC.REQUISITION_RELEASE_NO, WOC.RELEASE_NO, WOC.VER_NO, WOC.VER_DATE,
          WOC.INVOICE_ID, WOC.PURCHASE_ORDER_NO , WOC.PURCHASE_LINE_NO, WOC.PURCHASE_RELEASE_NO
          ) TOT
      ON TOT.VER_NO=DUPS.VER_NO and tot.purchase_order_no=dups.purchase_order_no and tot.purchase_line_no=dups.purchase_line_no and tot.purchase_release_no=dups.purchase_release_no

    LEFT JOIN 
          (
          select POL.order_no, POL.line_no, POL.release_no, POL.buy_qty_due, POL.buy_unit_price , POL.buy_qty_due * POL.buy_unit_price as linetot, POL.ORIGINAL_QTY from purchase_Order_line_tab  POL
          )PO
      on PO.order_no=dups.PURCHASE_ORDER_NO and PO.line_no=dups.PURCHASE_LINE_NO and po.release_no=dups.PURCHASE_RELEASE_NO


    where po.linetot<> tot.totamount
    order by dups.wo_no, dups.PURCHASE_ORDER_NO, dups.PURCHASE_LINE_NO, dups.PURCHASE_RELEASE_NO) taba) where rn >1;
```

Comment: Hi Ankit.. What is rn here?

Comment: rn is the rank generated by row_number function. suppose you have 3 rows and one column. first row has value 1, second row has 2 and third row has 1 again. so rank given to first row is 1,second row is 1 and to 3rd row will be 2. so if we do rn >1 we will get duplicate rows.

Comment: Thanks Ankit.. But I'm unable to select the WO_NO only to delete the records. The reason is, if I consider wo_no 30, the query can give that there are 3 duplicate records. But in the whole table there can be 7 records from wo_30. so deleting any 2 from that 7 will not work. We somehow have to find a way to uniquely identify the duplicated rows in the table.

Comment: You can select Hiru, Instead of taba.* write taba.wo_no. Give column alias to row_number() over(partition by WO_NO order by null) as rn

Comment: you want to delete records based on the query you have given to us or you just want to delete records from WORK_ORDER_CODING_TAB  table?

Comment: I need to delete duplicate records from table WORK_ORDER_CODING_TAB based on the given query results.

Comment: Can you please provide sample result, like 3 to 4 rows having duplicates and what is your expected output. that will really help. thanks